# Need help writing a bonobo XML writer transformation after reading from MySQL(SQLAlchemy)

Tags: python, mysql, xml, etl, bonobo-etl

So I'm a little new to bonobo and am trying to figure it out. I am also new to python a little bit so this project has been a little intimidating. I am trying to convert a mysql (using SQLAlchemy as a service) input stream into an XML output.  I have successfully set up my database stream, but I am kinda lost on how to create a transformation that will iterate over the result of my select. Anyone know of some examples of this?

The official examples are simply calling built in writer functions (CsvWriter, etc). I need to write one that will write out XML. I have looked at the internal code for the build in bonobo writer functions, but I'm still confused on how to write my own writer. Does anyone know of some examples of a custom writer that's simple enough for a beginner.

Or maybe can write a quick example of a VERY simple example that iterates over the results of a query?

I am using

```
bonobo_sqlalchemy.Select('SELECT * FROM UserData')
```

as my first transformation in my chain, and I have been able to prettyprint the results of my select... so that's working. I just need an example transformation which iterates over the collection.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve what you describe is to use a context processor.

```
import bonobo


def xml_document(self, context):
    context.send('<document>')
    yield
    context.send('</document>')


@bonobo.config.use_context_processor(xml_document)
def make_me_an_xml(id, name):
    yield '  <id>{id}</id><name>{name}</name>'.format(id=id, name=name)


def get_graph(**options):
    graph = bonobo.Graph(
        [{
            'id': 1,
            'name': 'Jane'
        }, {
            'id': 2,
            'name': 'John'
        }], bonobo.UnpackItems(0), bonobo.OrderFields(['id', 'name']), make_me_an_xml, print
    )
    return graph


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with bonobo.parse_args() as options:
        bonobo.run(get_graph(**options))
```

The reason why you can't do it directly in your function is that nodes in bonobo work with a one-call-per-input-row logic, and have no idea (by default) about the whole execution context.

It allows to keep the transformation functions stateless. But you can indeed decorate with job-length logic that bonobo understands.

Note that this API will probably evolve in the future, as it's not completely satisfying.

If you really need to use the context in the row level transformation, you can also decorate your transformation with the `@bonobo.config.use_context` decorator.

Hope that helps.

Comment: "If you really need to use the context in the row level transformation, you can also decorate your transformation with the @bonobo.config.use_context decorator."

Well the problem is I need the field names, which are not passed in with the data. context.get_input_fields() is what I am after. Maybe there's a better way to get the field names?

Comment: You can also use @bonobo.config.use_raw_input that will pass the named tuple as one argument, then use row._fields on it to get the field names.

Comment: @Romain could this also be achieved by subclassing the FileWriter class and implementing the write function instead?

Comment: @James Of course you can also do it by subclassing. I prefer to avoid subclassing when I can, as I feel it gives more than one responsibility to the node (which makes testing harder, for example), but both can work.